# Create dropdown using ASP.NET MVC4 and Entity Framework is used for database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create dropdown list using ASP.NET MVC4  and Entity Framework is used for database connectivity.
Problem is that I want create a new department name item in this dropdown list when click on it a javascript prompt is open with text box and ask for new department from end user. where he/she can add new department with his own desire and this is store in database and show in dropdown list after save.

Comment: You can work with JQuery and Ajax It will help you to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks. But i need solution. I am new in ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: Pleade read the FAQ. Members are not here to make your job. The purpose of the site is to solve concrete problem not work instead of You.